# Symfony2. When using querybuilder on entity with foreign keys, how to return values of foreign keys as sequence of ids?

Tags: angularjs, symfony, query-builder

I have query in my repository, that returns array result:

```
$result = $qb
            ->select('partial u.{id, username, email, lastLogin}', 'partial groups.{id}')
            ->leftJoin('u.groups', 'groups')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
```

When I requests this query on my AngularJS app, I getting next result:

```
[
  {"id":1,
   "username":"Sergio Ivanuzzo",
   "email":"my_email@domain.com",
   "lastLogin":null,
   "groups":[{"id":1}]
  }
]
```

Because of `groups` contains array of objects, I can't parse them in my editable directive (checkboxes not checked):

```
<span
    data-pk="{{ user.id }}"
    editable-checklist="user.groups"
    e-ng-options="g.id as g.name for g in groups"
    e-form="rowform">
    {{ User.showGroups(user) }}
</span>
```

When `groups` attribute contains something like [1,2,3] directive is working (checkboxes are checked normally).

So, for fixing this I'm parsing each User object from response:

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function(user) {
    var groups = [];
    angular.forEach(user.groups, function(group) {
        groups.push(group.id);
    });

    user.groups = groups;
});

$scope.users = response.data;
```

I feel, that I can avoid this workaround, If I could return `groups` for each user as sequence of numbers. How can I do this? Maybe better way exists?

If you need extra data, please, let me know! Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter to preserve your original data like

```
$scope.toArray = function(groupsAsObjects) {
    var groups = [];
    angular.forEach(groupsAsObjects, function(group) {
        groups.push(group.id);
    });
    return groups;
};
```

And

```
<span
    data-pk="{{ user.id }}"
    editable-checklist="user.groups | toArray"
    e-ng-options="g.id as g.name for g in groups"
    e-form="rowform">
    {{ User.showGroups(user) }}
</span>
```

Or remap your full array of objects as arrays like this :

```
$scope.toArray = function(obj, addKey) {
    if (!obj)
        return obj;
    if (addKey === false) {
        return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
            return obj[key];
        });
    } else {
        return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
            return Object.defineProperty(obj[key], '$key', {
                enumerable: false,
                configurable: true,
                value: key
            });
        });
    }
};
```